# How to Make Multi Text Animation with Different Position using CSS

Tags: css, animation, css-selectors, css-animations

I want to get 5 name display animation done like I have 5 names

1. James
2. Selina
3. George
4. Kim
5. Abraham

Each name should appear in a different position.
I have this demo, video is coming in it now
To replace the video with text animation

**like this but text animation**
https://www.agora.io/en/

I am working now but issue is happening in different position please if you have any solution then you can give me here

**I'm working on it right now:**
https://valudas.com/Consultancy-Design/

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="fly-in">  
<div><span>Virat</span>Kohli</div>
<div>Rohit<span>Sharma</span></div>
<div>Rishabh<span> Pant</span></div>
<div><span>Mohammad</span> Shami</div>
<div><span>Jasprit</span>Bumrah</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700');



body {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#333, #111);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#fly-in {
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 40vh auto;
  height: 20vh; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#fly-in span {
  display: block;
  font-size: .4em;
  opacity: .8;
}

#fly-in div {
 position: fixed; <!--codepen.io/h-kod/-->
  margin: 2vh 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 10vw;
  width: 80vw;
  animation: switch 32s linear infinite;
}

#fly-in div:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 4s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 8s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 12s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 16s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 20s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: 24s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(8) { animation-delay: 28s}

@keyframes switch {
    0% { opacity: 0;filter: blur(20px); transform:scale(12)}
    3% { opacity: 1;filter: blur(0); transform:scale(1)}
    10% { opacity: 1;filter: blur(0); transform:scale(.9)}
    13% { opacity: 0;filter: blur(10px); transform:scale(.1)}
    80% { opacity: 0}
    100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please put enough code actually into your question so we can see the problem. What position changes have you put into your keyframes?

Comment: @AHaworth i upload code here. you can see and reply me ASAP

Comment: There is oothing in the keyframes that alters the position of a name. Scale scales around a fixed point.

Comment: can you answer here?

Comment: You can read up about CSS animation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation Try adding a translate value to the transforms in the keyframes and work out exactly how much time you want each to show and where and then alter the timings in proportion.